# Запуск gearman воркера из консоли: Class GearmanWorker not found

Tags: php, консоль, ubuntu

Командой

> php worker.php &

пытаюсь запустить gearman, чтобы он выполнялся постоянно. Однако получаю ошибку, что класс GearmanWorker не найден.
Если я создам в каком-нибудь файле объект данного класса и запущу этот файл, то ошибок не будет.
var_dump выдаст

> object(GearmanWorker)#1 (0) { }

что, по сути, и должно быть. Однако консоль отказывается запускать данный скрипт. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: @MrGaliev Gearman капризен в плане установки. Возможно, он или pecl-extension некорректно установились. Проверить, запущен ли демон: `sudo service gearman-job-server status`. Проверить, установлен ли extension: `php -m`.

У меня имеются актуальные [настройки оного для Travis CI](https://github.com/romeOz/rock/blob/master/tests/data/travis/gearman-setup.sh)

Comment: > Однако консоль отказывается запускать данный скрипт.

Бывает, что достаточно указать extension для CLI:

    touch /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gearman.ini
    echo 'extension=gearman.so' >>  /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gearman.ini

Answer (score 1):

[[@MrGaliev](/users/18121/mrgaliev)](/users/18121/mrgaliev), возможно (возможно!), этот класс подгружается автоматически, но код проверяет его наличие в рантайме без попытки загрузки (`class_exists('GearmanWorker', false)`). В этом случае его надо подгрузить до выполнения, простого `class_exists('GearmanWorker')` должно хватить. Возможно, там модифицируется include_path или что-нибудь в этом духе.

Comment: Может быть все что угодно, но class_exists точно не помогает. Обращусь в тп